# Change Nuxt Store Variable

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm looking to change a variable within my Nuxt store, though it's passing the object. The logging is working nicely, returning the correct text from the clicked button. Though, within my mutation it's returning the entire object clicked instead of the text?

I have the following setup in my nuxt store as a mutation:

```js
      export const mutations = {
        changeSortOption(option) {
          console.log(option)
        }
      }
```

Then my method on my template:

```html
    <div v-for="item in options" :key="item.id">
       <button @click="changeSortOption(item.name)">{{ item.name }}</button>
    </div>
```

...

```js
    methods: {
        changeSortOption(option) {
            console.log(option)
            this.$store.commit('sort/changeSortOption', option)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutation's first argument should be state and second one (optional) is payload. So in your case it should be like that:

```
  export const mutations = {
    changeSortOption(state, option) {
      console.log(option)
    }
  }
```

More details you will find here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#commit-with-payload

Comment: Yep, just landed on that page. Thank you. I was trying to be too lazy.